# Own data var for each element

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm creating a jquery plugin and I need to give a variable at each targeted elements.
My problem is that when I do this in my js:

```
$("section ul").cards("init", {
    current: 0
}).on("mousewheel", mousewheel);

function mousewheel(){
    $(this).cards("next");
};
```

The plugin is censed to `console.log()` the updated `current`. But he update the same data to all "ul".

When I `mousewheel` in the first `ul`, the current for it become 1 (start is 0) and just after I `mousewheel` in the second `ul` and the current become 2...

I want every object his own variable (`$(this).data()`)

Thanks !

!! EDIT !!

There is my plugin base:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.cartes = function( methode, options ){

        if(options){
            return methodes[methode].apply(this, $.makeArray(options));
        }
        else {
            return methodes[methode].call(this);
        };

    };

    var methodes = {
        init: function( options ){

            return this.each(function(){

                var $this = $(this);
                var Options = $.meta ? $.extend( $.fn.cartes.defauts, options, $this.data() ) : options;

                $this.data("options", Options);

                $this.each(function(index){

                    $this.data("options").rotation = $.fn.cartes.defauts.rotation;
                    $this.data("options").espacement = $.fn.cartes.defauts.espacement;

                });

            });

        },
        prec: function(obj){

            return $(obj).each(function(){
                $(this).data("options").cur--;
                console.log( $(this).data("options").cur );
            });

        },

        next: function(obj){

            return $(obj).each(function(){
                $(this).data("options").cur++;
                console.log( $(this).data("options").cur );
            });

        }
    };

    $.fn.cartes.defauts = {
        cur: 0,
        espacement: 0,
        rotation: -45
    };

})(jQuery);
```

!! EDIT 2 !!

When I use the each loop, the `console.log` in the `mousewheel` event return the good data.

```
$("section li.double ul").each(function(){
  $(this).cartes("init", {
    actuel: 0,
    selecteur: "li"
  });
});
```

But how to do it without each loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finaly, it is just because:

```
var Options = $.meta ? $.extend( $.fn.cartes.defauts, options, $this.data() ) : options;
```

replace it by:

```
var Options = $.extend( $.fn.cartes.defauts, options, $this.data() );
```

and it work!

Answer (score 1):

Within a plugin it's usual to use a `.each` loop to apply the plugin to each element, e.g.:

```
init: function(opts) {
    return $.each(function() {
        ...
    });
}
```

where you can then use `.data` within the `.each` loop, giving each element its own data.  You'll also need to clone the object with `$.extend()` before storing it in `.data()`, otherwise each element will still share a reference to the same data.

Answer (score 1):

```
;(function($){
  $.fn.extend({
    cards: function(){
      return this.each(function(i,e){
        //
        // additional plugin logic
        //

        // `this` represents every item you're manipulating. here you
        // can assign `.data()` to each one (with its own specific value(s)).
        // For instance:
        $(this).data('whatevername', 'whatevervalue');

        //
        // additional plugin logic
        //
      });
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Something like that?

Comment: I do that, but when i console.log() one of the $(this).data(), all elements return the same data.

Comment: Are you sure they're the exact same data (i.e. the same objects), or just _look like_ the same data?

Comment: @Jordon if you're performing the same initialization on all the owns they are young to have the same data to start.

Answer (score 0):

You have to dereference the position of the mousepointer to get the card it is currently hovering above.